# How to dynamically set the colour of a 'div' element to match that of the colour picked on a colour widget using for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html code that includes a colour widget picker, the background of the entire page will change according to which pre-defined choice the user clicks on. I have got that working but I would like to highlight the box around the colour choice once it has been clicked to differentiate from the other unselected choices.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8" />
<title></title>
<script>
function changeColor(e) {
document.getElementById("page").className = e;

var i;
var x = document.getElementById("page");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)


if (document.getElementById("page").className = e ){
x.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].style.borderColor = "red";
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page" class=""><!-- start page wrapper -->

<hr />

<div id="theme-picker">
<h2>Theme Picker</h2>
<p>Select a theme from the options below:</p>
<div id="palette">
<ul>
<li class="midnight" onClick="changeColor('midnight')">Midnight</li>
<li class="matrix" onclick="changeColor('matrix')">Matrix</li>
<li class="peardrop" onclick="changeColor('peardrop')">Peardrop</li>
<li class="skylight" onclick="changeColor('skylight')">Skylight</li>
<li class="sunset" onclick="changeColor('sunset')">Sunset</li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>


<hr />



</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this (of course change the classes as needed):

```js
$('.changeColor').click(function(){
 var $this=$(this);
    var color=$this.data('color');
    $('#page').removeClass('midnight matrix peardrop skylight sunset').addClass(color);
    $('.changeColor').removeClass('highlight'); // jquery actually implements a loop here it's just internal...
    $this.addClass('highlight');
});


/*
   // Methods with a explicit loop per your comment

$('.changeColor').click(function(){
 var $this=$(this);
    var $page=$('#page');
    var color=$this.data('color');
    $page.removeClass('midnight matrix peardrop skylight sunset').addClass(color);
    $page.find('li').each(function(){  // jQuery loop....not really neccisary though...
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    });
    $this.addClass('highlight');
});

$('.changeColor').click(function(){
 var $this=$(this);
    var $page=$('#page');
    var color=$this.data('color');
    $page.removeClass('midnight matrix peardrop skylight sunset').addClass(color);
    var lis = $page.find('li');
    for(var i =0; i< lis.length; i++){ // js loop....again not really neccisary though...
      $(lis[i]).removeClass('highlight');
    }
    $this.addClass('highlight');
});

*/
```

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.midnight{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
.matrix{
    background-color:purple;
}
.peardrop{
    background-color:grey;
}
.skylight{
    background-color:blue;
}
.sunset{
    background-color:pink;
}
.highlight{
    background-color:yellow;
    outline: 1px solid #red;
    color:black;
    
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page" class=""><!-- start page wrapper -->

<hr />

<div id="theme-picker">
<h2>Theme Picker</h2>
<p>Select a theme from the options below:</p>
<div id="palette">
<ul>
<li class="changeColor" data-color="midnight">Midnight</li>
<li class="changeColor" data-color="matrix">Matrix</li>
<li class="changeColor" data-color="peardrop">Peardrop</li>
<li class="changeColor" data-color="skylight">Skylight</li>
<li class="changeColor" data-color="sunset">Sunset</li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>


<hr />
</div>
```

Comment: Any way to do it using a for loop? 

    var i;
    var x = document.getElementById("page");

    for (i=0;i<1;i++)

    {
    if (document.getElementById("page").className = e ){
    x.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].style.borderColor = "red";
  
    }
    }

This some what works, however it highlights all the boxes. Any way to only highlight the clicked box?

@DelightedD0D

Comment: $("#page").removeClass().addClass(color) would be more correct instead of specifying each and every class to remove

Comment: IDs must be unique, you cant have multiple elements with the id "page"

Comment: @Snm True, **assuming** that the OP's actual code does not make use of other classes on those elements at all. If there were more than a few, i'd agree. With just this many though, I'd prefer to be explicit

Comment: @TanmimHanifa What do you mean by "this highlights all the boxes"? It only highlights the clicked element

Comment: @DelightedD0D Im talking about the code i added up top with the for loop. I need to implement a for loop into the script

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the for loop? `$('.changeColor').removeClass('highlight'); $this.addClass('highlight');` will already do what you need (ie it will remove the `highlight` class from all `li`s and add it back to only the clicked `li` ), you just have to adjust the CSS for the `highlight` class to apply whatever effect you want. I jjust made it yellow for the demo

Comment: @DelightedD0D It's in my coursework specification to implement a for loop

Comment: See my update, there are several ways, here are a few

Comment: @TanmimHanifa You should look at my answer. You wouldn't need to include jQuery (which you don't seem to be using). I was missing the toggle to know which element is selected, but now it should be good enough for you to use

Answer (score -2):

You could pass the object everytime you call the function, and then change that object color. Something like this:

```
...
<script>
function changeColor(className,object) {
  document.getElementById("page").className = className;
  var siblings = object.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(var sibling in siblings){
    if(siblings[sibling].className){
      siblings[sibling].className = siblings[sibling].className.split(' ')[0];
    }
  }
  object.className = object.className+' selected';
}
</script>
...
<li class="midnight" onClick="changeColor('midnight',this)">Midnight</li>
<li class="matrix" onclick="changeColor('matrix',this)">Matrix</li>
<li class="peardrop" onclick="changeColor('peardrop',this)">Peardrop</li>
<li class="skylight" onclick="changeColor('skylight',this)">Skylight</li>
<li class="sunset" onclick="changeColor('sunset',this)">Sunset</li>
...
```

Edited, since I was missing the point of resetting the selection. You could just create a `selected` class with whatever you need and your done

Comment: What about removing the effect from the last sellection?

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that point. I edited it now. Thanks for your correction

Comment: @Piyin any way to use a for loop to highlight the selection?? I update my code to what i got so far and it is closer to what im requiring, however currently all boxes get highlighted and i need the clicked box to only highlight