# how to use for loop to cycle through lists of elements and set an elements style dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented a for loop to highlight the colour widget choices upon clicking one, however would like to only highlight the one that is clicked, the rest being without any border highlight. How would i go about this with just slight alterations to my code below? It is imperative to implement a for loop and pure javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8" />
<title></title>
<script>
function changeColor(e) {
document.getElementById("page").className = e;

var i;
var x = document.getElementById("page");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)


if (document.getElementById("page").className = e ){
x.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].style.borderColor = "red";
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page" class=""><!-- start page wrapper -->

<hr />

<div id="theme-picker">
<h2>Theme Picker</h2>
<p>Select a theme from the options below:</p>
<div id="palette">
<ul>
<li class="midnight" onClick="changeColor('midnight')">Midnight</li>
<li class="matrix" onclick="changeColor('matrix')">Matrix</li>
<li class="peardrop" onclick="changeColor('peardrop')">Peardrop</li>
<li class="skylight" onclick="changeColor('skylight')">Skylight</li>
<li class="sunset" onclick="changeColor('sunset')">Sunset</li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>


<hr />



</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have already asked this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically set the colour of a 'div' element to match that of the colour picked on a colour widget using for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925760/how-to-dynamically-set-the-colour-of-a-div-element-to-match-that-of-the-colour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the loop to this:

```
var i;
var x = document.getElementById("palette");
var items = x.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var item = items[i];
    item.style.borderColor = item.className == e ? "red" : "";
}
```

Comment: absolute lifesaver! One niggle, the border highlight stays even after selecting another box

Comment: Try changing `"none"` to `null` or `""`